# Why doesn't QComboBox.findData() accept an object as input?

Tags: pyside, python-3.4, qcombobox

I attach an object as UserData to a QStandardItem which gets added to an QComboBox model. If I then search for it with the findData()-method I get no result. If I do the same with a simple int I get a result. I suppose this is PySide related but I couldn't find the wrapper in the source. Here is a (somewhat) minimal example:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value


class MyCombo(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, *args)

        combo = QtGui.QComboBox()
        combo.addItem(str(1), Foo(1))
        combo.addItem(str(2), 2)

        data = combo.itemData(0)
        print(data)  # prints the object repr
        print(combo.findData(data))  # returns -1 -> not found

        data = combo.itemData(1)
        print(data)  # prints 2
        print(combo.findData(data))  # returns 1 -> found

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyCombo()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Why does findData() return -1 for the object? Any hints for what can be searched for are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [QT C++ doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#findData) provides an explanation. Here's the definition of `findData`, emphasis mine:

> int QComboBox::findData(const **QVariant & data**, int role =
>   Qt::UserRole, Qt::MatchFlags flags = static_cast (
>   Qt::MatchExactly | Qt::MatchCaseSensitive )) const

The data in a combobox can only be a [QVariant](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qvariant.html#details), which is "a union for the most common Qt data types". So data can only be a common Qt data type, which does not include a regular python class.

However, data can be a `QtCore.QObject`, so your issue is easily solved:

```
class Foo(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, value,parent=None):
        super(Foo,self).__init__(parent)
        self.value = value

class MyCombo(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, *args)

        combo = QtGui.QComboBox()
        combo.addItem(str(1),Foo(1,self) )

        data = combo.itemData(0)
        print("data",data)  # prints the object repr
        print(combo.findData(data))  # returns 0 -> found
```

NB: `QVariant` are used in C++ because you need to define every value with a type (like `int i=0;`). In python, you don't need this, as a value can change type at any time. So in PySide, `QVariant` is not implemented, instead they use the regular python types or Qt types.

Comment: This is actually a bug (or at least a missing feature) in pyside and pyqt4. When comparing custom types (such as python objects), `QVariant` should use the address of the contained value. This has been fixed in pyqt5, where the OPs example will work as expected. I don't know the details of the implementation, but I suspect a special meta-type is registered for wrapping python types so they can be contained in a `QVariant`. Possibly the issue here is that pyside/pyqt4 is comparing the addresses of the temporary *wrappers* rather than the contained values.

Comment: In this case your approach works perfectly fine, but unfortunately my real code is much more complex and i dont want to subclass QObject for the solution. I now do the most obvious and iterate over the elements und compare them to find the correct element. I was more interested in the reason for this strange behaviour but your answer and @ekhumoro's very helpful comment helped solve this mystery!

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't work for me either.

I subclassed QComboBox to write the `findData` method myself:

```
from PySide import QtGui


class QComboBox(QtGui.QComboBox):
    def findData(self, data):
        for index in range(self.count()):
            if self.itemData(index) == data:
                return index
        return -1
```

Comment: seems to be fixed in PySide2